# How can I make skybox drawing easier in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, painting

I am using Photoshop CC to draw a skybox -that is, an image composed of six sub-images that seamlessly assemble into a cube, like this:

[image: Skybox]

As soon as I started drawing, I noticed that it is very difficult to make the image seamlessly loop across the different faces of the skybox.

I would like to know if there is a way to simplify the process of drawing such an image.

What I'm currently doing is to put guides in a grid the size of my skybox, paint, and then manually rotate the different faces to various configurations, and fix the seams. It is a very complicated work, and I would like to believe there is a better way to do this.

For example, I would like to be able to take a face of my image, copy it, rotate it and place the copy in a different part of the image, and make it so drawing on one of the copies automatically updates the other copy. I don't know how to do this, or if it is even doable in Photoshop.

Are there any ways to streamline the creation of such drawings in Photoshop?

Comment: you can map it on a 3d cube and paint on top of that.

Comment: @joojaa: How do you do that?

Comment: Doing a skybox in PS is tedious. What about an external tool?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? I want to paint the skyboxes, not get them automatically generated.

Comment: Well if you want to paint them: http://www.interlopers.net/tutorials/28841

Comment: You better buy some patience! ;)

Comment: Yes, I'm currently painting them in a similar way. I just want to know if there are ways to make the process simpler.

Comment: There are fastest ways but not in Photoshop.

Comment: Once again, what tool do you propose?

Comment: This is my approach: take the pictures, create the panorama, go to 3ds max or blender, create a box, apply UV mapping, choose projection method to spherical, bake the textures. More steps, but less time.

Comment: That would be a process to simplify the process of -testing- of the image, not -creating- the image. Testing is not a problem for me, because I can put it on my game engine and test it pretty hassle-free.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17193/discussion-between-neo-and-panda-pajama).

Comment: Not clear on your set up. Are you working six images separately and the guides are reference points for matching features? Why not work in one large image like the reference above, then cut that into the six cube faces?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve what you want with photoshop **Smart Objects**

- right click on layer name (1 square out of 6 squares) and select *Convert to Smart Object*
- to edit it double click to open in a new window
- when you save it it will update in the main window

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't considered that option. It would be even better if I could edit on the main window, and get the sides updated automatically. Do you know if there's a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any good way for you to do this in Photoshop as-is.
I would highly suggest you look at Quixel DDO + 3DO. It integrates directly with Photoshop and would allow you to paint in 3D using Photoshop brushes. It's fairly overkill for what you need, but should help you out.

https://quixel.se/suite2/